# How to build a sitemap using Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I need to create a Sitemap for a Sitecore website. How can I do this?

Comment: same question was asked a day later. The answer was the same. just letting you know. Here is the link for the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979405/sitecore-how-to-generate-a-sitemap-xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're after a sitemap page to list the pages on your site you should try the Shared Source module 'Sitemap'.
http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitemap.aspx

However, if you're after a sitemap for search engine optimization, use Sitemap XML.
http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitemap_XML.aspx

Comment: I've set this up but I just get a blank XML file - tried including every template we're using, and I've tripple-checked all the config file settings...

Comment: The same happens for me as it did for @LeviWallach. Is there any documentation that takes you from installation to it funcioning as expected?

Comment: I have Sitemap XML working in Sitecore 9. To get it working I removed the default site entries in SitemapXML.config under '<sites>' and added the appropriate entries for my multi site solution, then I added the page templates for the pages I wanted to add to the XML sitemap in the 'Enabled templates' field of the '/sitecore/system/Modules/Sitemap XML/Sitemap configuration' item.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need as a Sitemap. Do you want an XML sitemap that goes to Google?
Or do you want a sitemap that shows the structure of your website?

I'd suggest looking at the Sitecore marketplace (http://marketplace.sitecore.net/SearchResults#query=sitemap), possibly downloading the source code to see how it's done. I think there's an example for both.

Otherwise, you can also create your own, but we'll need some more information - do you want to write it in XSLT or using codebehind such as C#?