# Sitecore - How to generate a sitemap xml

Tags: sitecore

I need to generate a sitemap xml for our sitecore project. I have seen it's done with Nicam example. How can I do this?

(I have asked the same question in a previous post, sorry about the duplicate quesiton, I have removed that. That was a mistake)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicated question?

Comment: I thought it was groundhog day! Dupe.

Comment: Not only is it a duplicate, it's the same user asking the question! Sorry, down vote!

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate question. The same question has been asked yesterday also ;)

If you're after a sitemap page to list the pages on your site you should try the Shared Source module 'Sitemap'.
http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitemap.aspx

However, if you're after a sitemap for search engine optimization, use Sitemap XML.
http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitemap_XML.aspx

See the [original post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956383/how-to-build-a-sitemap-using-sitecore/14956563#14956563)

Answer (score 0):

There is a module available in the Sitecore Marketplace called SitemapXML. It's downloadable from http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitemap_XML.aspx. You can also write your own custom logic to create an sitemap xml defined by your customer's needs.